# How do I split number string with digit pattern?

Tags: data-wrangling

I am trying to split number string to two to digit numbers

How do I get two different Numbers out that string

Example:

I want separate two numbers

```
x <- c("-26755.22-50150.60")
```

To this

```
-26755.22
-50150.60
```

I have tried `stringr::str_split` but I din't manage to keep the digits.

Comment: I am using R for this

Comment: Do you have any delimiter? and the values are going to be like only 2 values after decimal right?

Comment: There is no delimiter. I know that after 2 digits i have to separate these numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the thing for you:

```
#the input
str <- " -26755.22-50150.60"    


#you can use this command to split the data into 2 columns
#this doesn't have any constraint in the number of digits before and after the decimal
strspl <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(str,gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",str, perl=TRUE))))
```

Outcome:

```
> strspl
[1] -26755.22 -50150.60
```

If you want to store the outcome in a data-frame then you can use the below command

```
#everything is same but instead of as.numeric we replace it with as.data.frame
str_df <- as.data.frame(unlist(regmatches(str,gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",str, perl=TRUE))))

#it is not necessary to change the column but it is a good practice to do so
colnames(str_df) <- "variable_1"
```

Outcome:

[image: Outcome in Dataframe]

Let me know if you have any doubt, would help you.

If you got what you are looking for, you can accept the answer by clicking on the green tick mark.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what is your regular expression doing?

Comment: @AnkitSeth: The regular expression works like this, it start with the decimal point and decimal fraction(optional) and allows multiple numbers to be extracted. (?>-) this is for the negative sign. hope I answered your question. Let me know if I'm not clear

Answer (score 1):

I just did this-

```
> library(stringr)
> x <- c("-26755.22-50150.60")
> matc = "\\-[0-9]*\\.[0-9]{2}"
> as.numeric(unlist(str_match_all(x, matc)))
[1] -26755.22 -50150.60
```

After this, you can select the numbers by using respective indexes.